# Node.js socket.io disconnect event won't trigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm developing an app using socket io but my diconnect trigger event isn't working, I did everything like the docs say and it's still the same... It was working a few days ago but now it's not working anymore, I didn't edit any code since then

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('event', function(data){});

var socketUsers = [];

io.use(sharedSession(session, {
    autoSave: true
}));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socketUsers.push(socket);

    console.log('Player connected: ' + socket.id); 
    console.log('Connected players: ' + socketUsers.length);

    io.on('disconnect', function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < socketUsers.length; i++) {
            console.log(socketUsers[i].id);
            if(socketUsers[i].id == socket.id) {
                //delete socketUsers[i];
                socketUsers.splice(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log(socketUsers.length + ' players online.');
    });
    io.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
    function broadcast(key, value) {
        io.emit(key, value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attaching the `disconnect` event handler to the server instance (`io`) and not the socket instance (`socket`).

So try this instead:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() { ... });
```